# How to disable insert and delete cells options from Excel using c#?

Tags: c#-4.0

How to disable insert and delete cells options from Excel using c#.
I don't want to insert or delete a cell once data bind from code.

[image]

Comment: anything tried yet ?

Comment: Editable = false?

Comment: document should be editable, I just need prevent insert new cells and preventing from deletion cells.